# Unhandled Exceptions Crashing VS 2008

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

In the last few weeks, I've had two occasions where the debug process (vshost.exe) crashes due to an unhanded exception.  The first was trying to use the Activator class to instantiate an object, I don't remember details, and today was trying to load a custom config section where I had erred in specifying the type for the section.  In both cases debugging proceeded correctly when I set the debugger to break when exceptions are thrown.

Anyone know anything about such an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to diagnose this try the following

- Tools -> Options -> Debugging
- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"

Then re-run your scenario.  When Just My Code is enabled, exceptions thrown in code not deemed to be yours will not be immediately displayed in the debugger.

Comment: @Jared: Thanks.  I can't check right now, but you reminded me that I have solved this problem before.